# Use Lodash map to reorganize list into sorted keys by value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am can't figure out how to do this without iterating over the array three times.

I am looking to transform an array of job listings that look like this:

```
const jobs = [
  {
    title: 'Manager',
    department: 'Retail',
    location: 'New York'
  },
  {
    title: 'Customer Service Rep',
    department: 'Corporate',
    location: 'Washington D.C.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Clerk',
    department: 'Retail',
    location: 'New York'
  },
  ...
];
```

Into an object of *unique* departments with associated jobs:

```
const deps = {
  'Corporate': [
    {
      title: 'Customer Service Rep',
      department: 'Corporate',
      location: 'Washington D.C.'
    },
  ],
  'Retail': [
    {
      title: 'Manager',
      department: 'Retail',
      location: 'New York'
    },
    {
      title: 'Clerk',
      department: 'Retail',
      location: 'New York'
    },
  ],
};
```

Is `_map` my best bet here? Is there a more eloquent way of doing this?

Comment: Looks like `groupBy`

Comment: Your result should be an object.

Comment: If it were me I'd just use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: @HassanImam you're right, I'm looking for an object. Question updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group jobs based on `department`.

```js
const jobs = [ { title: 'Manager', department: 'Retail', location: 'New York' }, { title: 'Customer Service Rep', department: 'Corporate', location: 'Washington D.C.' }, { title: 'Clerk', department: 'Retail', location: 'New York' }],
    deps = jobs.reduce((r,job) => {
      r[job.department] = r[job.department] || [];
      r[job.department].push(job);
      return r;
    },{});
console.log(deps);
```

You can use [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy)

```js
const jobs = [ { title: 'Manager', department: 'Retail', location: 'New York' }, { title: 'Customer Service Rep', department: 'Corporate', location: 'Washington D.C.' }, { title: 'Clerk', department: 'Retail', location: 'New York' }],
    deps = _.groupBy(jobs, 'department');
console.log(deps);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```